# Question about feature selection for support vector regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I am new to machine learning, and am having a problem with one stage in my planned analysis. I am trying to approach some of my EEG data with ML in order to determine which networks of functional connections in the brain are altered in infants who go on to develop autism. The predictor/response will be a behavioral 'ASD score', and around 300 connectivity values will serve as features. Sample size = 63.

From looking at similar approaches in the literature and applying them to my problem, my plan is to:

1) Perform cross-validated feature selection (determine which of the 300 will be most useful in my model).

2) Train a support vector regression model using leave-one-out methods to determine whether a model can predict later behavioral ASD scores.

3) Use beta weights to determine which neural connections most 'predict' later ASD score.

I am really struggling with moving from step 2 to 3... I know I can't simply check which connections are correlated with behavior across the entire sample and use these connections to train a leave one out model...

The best approach I have so far is using sequentialfs in Matlab with a leave one out partition. I feel like this is still biased though, as from what I can gather it B) for every N=63 training sample/fold builds a subset of features that best minimizes MSE, and B) chooses a feature subset from the N=63 folds with minimum MSE .... So going with this one feature subset would represents the fold with one subject left out, which seems akin to choosing connections based on the entire sample?